# Issue while setting string from a TextView to a TCPClient.class string IP

Tags: java, android, tcp

Good evening,
I'm trying to pass a text data from a **TextView** from MainActivity to Client.class ( **TCP client** ) and set it to another string ( actually i'm passing IP set in a TextView in MainActivity and just trying to load it in Client.class ) but when i'm trying to visualize it with a toast ( for test if i've passed the variable there is a stuff like this )

[image]

Here Client code :

```
public class Client {

static Intent intent = getIntent();
static String getIp = intent.getExtra("key");
private String serverMessage;
public static final String SERVERIP = getIp; //your computer IP address
public static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
private boolean mRun = false;

MainActivity main;
PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;
/**
 *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
 */
public Client(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Sends the message entered by client to the server
 * @param message text entered by client
 */
public void sendMessage(String message){
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
    }
}

public void stopClient(){
    mRun = false;
}

public void run() {

    mRun = true;

    try {
        //here you must put your computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        try {

            //send the message to the server
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

            //receive the message which the server sends back
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
            while (mRun) {
                serverMessage = in.readLine();

                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                }
                serverMessage = null;

            }

            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

        } finally {
            //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
            // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

    }

}

//Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
//class at on asynckTask doInBackground
public interface OnMessageReceived {
    void messageReceived(String message);
}
```

}

MainActivity :

```
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Client.class);
        i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", String.valueOf(indr));
```

Comment: `Intent.putExtra`

Comment: I actually don't have an OnCreate in the Client.class how can i retrive data from the Intent? could you make an example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `MainActivity` do something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Client.class);
i.putextra("key", IPTextView);
// IPTextView is the IP address you want to toast
```

and in your `Client class` do the following:

```
String getIp = getIntent.getExtra("key")
```

The you can `Toast` it like:

```
Toast.makeText(context, getIp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

---

The Other option you have is to save the IP address in `SharedPreferences` and get it back in `Client class`

---

Or you can create a static method with some return value, then you can get the IP in `Client class` through class name.

Comment: Just one more thing, when i write "String getIp = getIntent.getExtra("key")" in Client class that says "Cannot resolve symbol "getIntent"

Comment: Try `Intent intent = getIntent();`

Comment: Sorry try `Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();` because its not a `Activity`

Comment: What should i put in context?

Comment: I actually did this :     Context context;
    Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
    String getIp = intent.getExtra("key"); but getExtra is saying "canno't resolve method"